# After all these code still i cannot load csv to mysql

Tags: php

Any rewrite....debugs? nothing is happening

This is the php code for the import but still i when i upload the CSV...it doesnt at all...what could be the error!....any expertise?

```
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"> CSV:
        <input name="file" type="file" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload
        File" /></p> </form>

        <?php
          $connection = mysql_connect("51.63.225.22","mape","Leftie1982@")
          or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
          $db = mysql_select_db("mapsyracuse", $connection)
          or die ("Couldn't select database");

          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
          {
          $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

          $handle = fopen($file,"r");

          while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
            {
            $ID = $fileop[0];
            $Teritory = $fileop[1];
            $First_Name = $fileop[2];
            $Last_Name = $fileop[3];
            $Type = $fileop[4];
            $Activity_Description = $fileop[5];
            $Start_Date = $fileop[6];
            $End_Date = $fileop[7];
            $Duration = $fileop[8];
            $Status = $fileop[9];
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_manager(
            ID,
            Teritory,
            First_Name,
            Last_Name,
            Type,
            Activity_Description,
            Start_Date,
            End_Date,
            Duration,
            Status
            )
            VALUES( 
            '$ID',
            '$Teritory',
            '$First_Name',
            '$Last_Name',
            '$Type',
            '$Activity_Description',
            '$Start_Date',
            '$End_Date',
            '$Duration',
            '$Status')");
        }
        if($sql)
        {
                echo 'CSV file successfully imported.';
            }
        }

        ?>
```

which code do i add now???????

Comment: what have you done to debug this? how far does the code get until it breaks, what if any error's are returned?

Comment: *"which code do i add now!!!!!!!!!"* - that should be in a form of a question. Please search & replace `!!!!!!!!!` with `?????????`

Comment: Now for one thing, your submit button isn't named so it will ***"STOP DEAD in its tracks"*** with `<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />` using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: what do you mean...do i need to add a name for the submit...if(isset($_POST['submit']))...does it use the value

Comment: Dagon...there are no bugs..but it cant pick the csv

Comment: @eddstyson Your submit button needs (**MUST**) to be named

Comment: halfer...what do you mean...mysql_real_escape_string ..the how will i be able to upload the csv?

Comment: Here `input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" />` <= give that a whirl. @eddstyson

Comment: @eddstyson `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is **L@@KING** for a button named `submit` and yours is not named. Either you remove `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` or name your submit button as previously stated.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(507) : runtime-created function on line 55

Comment: @eddstyson Well, at least that's a "form of result" which you were not getting before. Now you need to debug your code/query. The answer is in the error message. Find that undefined variable.

Comment: very strange...when i upload the csv..CSV file successfully imported....but there is no data...

Comment: @eddstyson Probably because there is no connection to DB at time of execution. Try changing this `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_manager` to `$sql = mysql_query($connection, "INSERT INTO account_manager`

Comment: Fred -ii-many thanks...one step to kill this bug

Comment: Fred -ii...please could you rewrite

Comment: @eddstyson Rewrite what, did you try what I wrote and succeeded? What exactly is not working now?

Comment: @eddstyson Actually try `if($connection, $sql)` also. I use `MySQLi_` rather than `MySQL_` so it's easier for me to work with. You just need the DB connection to execute. Usual syntax is `mysql_query($sql, $con)` but in your case `mysql_query($sql, $connection)`

Comment: am using xampp 1.8.2...joomla 2.5.11

Comment: web server...Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

Comment: when i upload csv..it process...but the database still empty

Comment: @eddstyson Try putting this `mysql_query($sql,$connection);` on top of `if($sql)`

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 sec)

Comment: @eddstyson Well I don't know what else it could be at this point. Check your DB fields, see if they all correspond.

Comment: could you clarify for me what youment,,if($connection, $sql

Comment: i have addded..sql = mysql_query($connection, "INSERT INTO....i get error..Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(507) : runtime-created function on line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of problems in your code, which you should fix before you proceed:

- Possible SQL injection via the uploaded file - you are not escaping your user inputs. Do a search-engine search for "PHP mysql_real_escape_string" and read what the PHP manual has to say here
- Using a deprecated database library. If you fix this, you can use parameterisation, which fixes the first problem too
- No check made as to whether your database connection or query has succeeded
- Unclear and inconsistent indentation
- Closing paragraph tag (`</p>`) with no corresponding opening tag

Once you have fixed those issues, I suggest you then use `echo` and `exit` to debug this code - the problem could be any number of things.

Comment: One other problem is that the OP didn't name the submit button. `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is looking for one, but OP's submit input is `<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />` - So that alone will not execute anything till it is named. That won't guarantee the successful DB query, but at least the OP will start getting results.